# How to select all text between two patterns where the end pattern might also be a start pattern

Tags: shell, awk, pattern-matching

Lets say I have the following file

```
BREAK A
abc
BREAK B
bcd
BREAK A
cde
BREAK A
```

What I wish to do is to select everything between `BREAK A` and `BREAK`, including the line `BREAK A` so the desired output is

```
BREAK A
abc
BREAK A
cde
BREAK A
```

None of the awk samples I can find account for the possibility that I might use the same line as both the start and end of a matched segment.

P.S. I'm not sure if this will matter, but in the real file `BREAK` appears at the start of the line while `A` and `B` appears in the middle of a line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
awk '/^BREAK/ && !/^BREAK A/{p=0} /^BREAK A/{p=1} p' file

BREAK A
abc
BREAK A
cde
BREAK A
```

We're using `p` as toggle value that gets set when we find `BREAK A` in a line and gets reset when any other `BREAK` is found in a line.

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

With sed :

```
$ sed '/BREAK [^A]/,/BREAK A/{/BREAK A/!d}' file
BREAK A
abc
BREAK A
cde
BREAK A
```

Answer (score -2):

First it says print lines containing regex "BREAK A", the semicolon works as separator between statements. Then it says print lines either ending or starting with c.

```
awk '/BREAK A/;/c$|^c/' file
    BREAK A
    abc
    BREAK A
    cde
    BREAK A
```

Comment: Please add some explanations to the answer. That will help new users.